# Textbox value from dynamic ul on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the value of my dynamically created textboxes from within a collapsible div and dynamically created listview. each ul has a button. when the button click event fires I'm getting the first ul data and not the data from the ul where the button lives. My dynamic `<form>` element post the data fine since it is within the same ul as the button.

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
//event.stopPropagation();
    var form_data = {
        FDID: $('.fdid-1').val(),
        CHOICE1: $('.choice-1').val(),
        CHOICE2: $(".choice-2").val()
        };
});
```

...

```
$.each( data, function ( i, val ) {

        //var orders=this.aaData;
        // -----  SUB-ARRAY within DATA accessed via the orders var.      
            //$.each(val.aaData, function(property, value) {
            //var orderNum = value.LastName;
            //var itemNum = value.FirstName;

            ($('<div>')
            .attr({
                'data-role': 'collapsible',
                'data-content-theme': 'c',
                'data-collapsed': 'true',
                'id': 'cResults'
            })
            .html('<h4>' + this.LastName + ', ' + this.FirstName + '</h4>'
            + '<form class="productForm" action="modify.php" method="post">'
            + '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Choices..." data-inset="true" class="makecollapsibleul">'
            + '<li>'
            + '<label for="fdid-1">FDID:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="fdid-10" class="fdid-1" value=' + this.FDID + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + '<label for="text-1">Choice 1:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="choice-1" class="choice-1" value=' + this.C1 + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + '<label for="text-2">Choice 2:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="choice-2" class="choice-2" value=' + this.C2 + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 2: ' + this.C2 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 3: ' + this.C3 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 4: ' + this.C4 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 5: ' + this.C5 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'Choice 6: ' + this.C6 + '</li><li>' 
            + 'IP: ' + this.IPADDRESS + '</li><input type="submit" class="submit" value="UPDATE" /><li>' 
            + 'Pick Date: ' + this.PICKDATE + '</li>'
            + '</ul></form>'))
            .appendTo('#primary');

                    //$(".title").append('<li>'+orderNum+' -- '+itemNum+'</li>');

            $('#makecollapsible').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    //});     // end of sub-array
    });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="outer-ul">
        <li>  
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Submitted Choices</h4> 

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="makecollapsible">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>

        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>           
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple inputs with same class, `$(".myClass").val()` will return the first element value.

So, the solution is to get the form and find the inputs inside of the form:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");

    var form_data = {
        FDID: $('.fdid-1', $form).val(),
        CHOICE1: $('.choice-1', $form).val(),
        CHOICE2: $(".choice-2", $form).val()
    };
});
```

Comment: Wow - thank you so much, i've asked this question 3 different ways, I guess I finally spelled it out in a way that can be understood. That fixed my issue.

Comment: one small followup: So I want to disable the default behavior of the original form, is it best practice to just remove the post from the form or via `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @BarclayVision Ok, removed it. I also gave you an answer to the other question. I think it also helps you..

Comment: ?? I'm not sure I understand you answer? are you saying to "Remove" the post section of the form?

Comment: @BarclayVision I removed the commented line `e.stopPropagation()`. What do you mean?

Comment: I waned to know since I can now get the textbox values the way I want, should I disable the default behavior of the dynamic form I've created since it contains a post to my php page. ?

Comment: @BarclayVision It depends about the situation. I would do: `$(document).on("submit", "form", function () { return false; })` (**outside** of the click handler). This will disable the default browser behavior for all form in the page.